# "Cortar" uma variável

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho essa variável:

var exemplo = AcloseBcloseCclose;

Quero separar as palavras divididas por **close** e guardar cada uma numa variável.

Ex:

var exemplo = **A**close**B**close**C**close;

var a = A;

var b = B

var c = C;

como poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer isso usando arrays e o método `split`. Veja:

```js
var exemplo = 'AcloseBcloseCclose';
var variaveis = exemplo.split('close');
console.log(variaveis[0], variaveis[1], variaveis[2])
```